# How to pass select option values from html form to flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

```
Flask
```

As you can see my flask code I have two values 'run pipeline' and 'check state and result of pipeline but when I am executing the flask script it opens my html code in browser and when i select any operation which is like 'check state and result of pipeline' it should return me same string but it's not returning string, its returning only the html page which i have put in my else condition. Can anyone suggest what's the issue?

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app= Flask(__name__)
#@app.route('/')
@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/check', methods=['GET','POST'])
def check():
    if request.method=='POST':
        Operations=request.form['Operations']
        
        if(Operations=="Run Pipeline"):

            return ('index.html', Operations)

        elif (Operations=="Check state and result of pipeline"):
            
            return ('index.html', Operations)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Title</title>

</head>

<body>

<h1 style="background-color:blue;", title="This is to run and check state of azure devops pipelines using one-click">Azure Devops Pipeline</h1>
<hr>


<p>Choose Options to perform operation on pipeline:</p>



<form action="{{url_for('check')}}",method="post">

<!-- <label for='Operations'>Choose the operation to perform</label> -->
    <Select name="Operations" id='Operations' required='required'>

        <option value="Run Pipeline">Run Pipeline</option>
        <option value="Check state and result of pipeline">Check state and reult of pipeline</option>
    </Select><br><br>

    <button id="sub" type='submit'>Click me</button>

</form>



</body>
<hr>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `index.html` on line 23 you have an extra comma in there after the url for action

Your html:

```html
<form action="{{url_for('check')}}",method="post">
```

Fix:

```html
<form action="{{url_for('check')}}" method="post">
```

Although when you fix that and select a value in you form and submit it. You will get this as a result [image]

I'm not sure what you want the output be, so I'll leave it there.

Comment: ok that was my bad it was a syntax error what i want is when you click on run pipeline, it should print it over there on browser, how to get that value, because it is executing only else condition. what about this?

 Operations=request.form['Operations']
        
        if(Operations=="Run Pipeline"):

            return ('index.html', Operations)
why i am not getting Operations= 'Run Pipeline' when i am selecting 'Run Pipeline' , Is there anyway to get that?

Comment: ok i have got the answer i have removed else part and then i have also removed index.html from every return statement. Instead of request.form i used request.form.get('Operations), and i got desired o/p.